# Degree of dosage compensation in Drosophila melanogaster

Tags: genomics, genomes, drosophila, dosage-compensation

In [this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2674252/) the authors state that the dosage compensation seen in *Drosophila* is approximately twofold, but they do not provide any source or numbers (as far as I can see) for this. What is the mean degree of dosage compensation in *Drosophila (melanogaster)*? For example, if X linked genes are, on average, perfectly upregulated the X:AA ratio in males would be 1, while if they are nearly perfectly (but slightly under) upregulated it will be ~0.9.

[Here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/23760/imperfect-dosage-compensation) is a similar (but different) question RE perfection in DC in general (here I am specific to *Drosophila melanogaster*).

Comment: please explain downvote

Comment: I checked for RNAseq experiments in male and female drosophila but couldn't find any. If you can find one study then I can tell what is the mean degree of DC.

Comment: There are studies [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1240036/) and [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1240037/) which explore compensation *via* the MSL complex (I think Straub et al. has the correct info but they reference the Hamada paper as well). I apologize, I haven't time to read them thoroughly myself, if anyone could give them a look over.